# Why is the Mocked class constructor getting called since I specified the return?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to create a simple Moq example to mock a class passing the constructor:

```
string apiKey = "123";

Mock<YTAuthentication> authentication = new Mock<YTAuthentication>(apiKey);
authentication.Setup(p => p.ApiKey).Returns("123_c");
string toTest = authentication.Object.ApiKey;
```

The problem with this is it returns "123" instead of "123_c", I breakpointed the constructor and I confirmed it gets hit

Here is the class being mocked.

```
public class YTAuthentication : IYTAuthentication
{
    public virtual string ApiKey { get; }

    public YTAuthentication(string apiKey)
    {
        ApiKey = apiKey;
    }
}

public interface IYTAuthentication
{
    string ApiKey { get; }
}
```

I think I am missing some concept here but I can't grasp what it is

Comment: Ok my next question would be why mock the class and not the interface?

Comment: What version of Moq are you using? This worked correctly for me when tested with 4.10

Comment: @RollRoll I just ran your code and it behaves as expected. Check your version.

Comment: I'm using Moq 4.10.0 and testing it on NUnit. I removed passing the constructor to the Mocked instance and it worked. I wondering how it worked for your guys with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass `apiKey` as a parameter for the mock, you can simply do:

```
Mock<IYTAuthentication> authentication = new Mock<IYTAuthentication>(); // no arguments
authentication.Setup(p => p.ApiKey).Returns("123_c");
string toTest = authentication.Object.ApiKey;
```

That `Mock`'s overload you are calling takes an array of objects as parameters and tries to initialize the mocked object with the parameters you pass to it which overrides the setup.

**Edit:**

As @JonathonChase pointed out, you don't need to mock the concrete implementation of `IYTAuthentication`, you can simply make mocks out of interfaces which will come out as something like anonymous objects that implement the target interface. And assuming that your code follows the good principle of [Dependency Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) then it is safe to assume that whatever service you are trying to test depends not upon the concrete `YTAuthentication` but rather the abstraction of it which is `IYTAuthentication`, so following this good practice your unit test would look like this:

```
var authenticationMock = new Mock<IYTAuthentication>(); // no arguments

authenticationMock.Setup(p => p.ApiKey).Returns("123_c");

var service = new ServiceToTest(authenticationMock.Object);

var data = service.GetData();

Assert.Equal("expected data", data);
```

Comment: If you try this with the code provided you will get an `InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException`, as he's mocking a concrete class that lacks a parameterless constructor.

Comment: You should go ahead and point out that you're mocking the interface over the concrete class, which I would agree to be the better practice.